# How to fix syntax error in socket io setence

Tags: python, socket.io

We have the following python code:

```
ListenPort = 'http://180.13.1.245:3011'
    
sio = socketio.Client()
sio = socketio.AsyncClient()

@sio.event
def connect():
    print("Connected!")
@sio.event
def connect_error():
    print("Connection failed!")

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print("Disconnected!")

await sio.connect(ListenPort)
```

And as result, after compilation:

```
await sio.connect(ListenPort)
    ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error tells you, you can only use `await` in a function. Also that function has to be a coroutine (a function defined with `async def`). You can solve your error by wrapping the code in a coroutine and running that:

```
import asyncio


async def main():
    ListenPort = 'http://180.13.1.245:3011'
    
    sio = socketio.Client()
    sio = socketio.AsyncClient()
    
    @sio.event
    def connect():
        print("Connected!")
    @sio.event
    def connect_error():
        print("Connection failed!")
    
    @sio.event
    def disconnect():
        print("Disconnected!")
    
    await sio.connect(ListenPort)


asyncio.run(main())
```